# jQuery template doesn't display content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I've been trying to learn to use jQuery Javascript Templates. I was following the tutorial here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-working-with-the-official-jquery-templating-plugin/ (which takes receives tweets from twitter).

I believe I have followed the code perfectly, I have put it here http://jqupload.herokuapp.com/tmpl

The code is here. All the scripts/stylesheets seem to be referenced correctly and the code seems to be correct according to the tutorial.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/tmpl-style.css" />
      <script src="public/javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="public/javascripts/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1> Tweets about Nettuts+ </h1>
      <script id="tweets" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
         <li>
            <img src="${imgSource}" alt="${username}" />
            <h2> ${username} </h2>
            <p> ${tweet} </p>
            {{if geo}} 
            <span>
               ${geo} 
            </span>
            {{/if}} 
         </li>
      </script>
      <ul id="twitter"></ul>
      <script>
         $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            dataType : 'jsonp',
            url : 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=nettuts',
            success : function(tweets) {
               var twitter = $.map(tweets.results, function(obj, index) {
                  return {                      
                     username : obj.from_user,
                     tweet : obj.text,
                     imgSource : obj.profile_image_url,
                     geo : obj.geo
                  };
               });
               $('#tweets').tmpl(twitter).appendTo('#twitter');
            }
      });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Using firebug I can see that the correct information is received from Twitter, but the tweets don't actually get displayed. Can anyone please help?

Comment: FWIW, jQuery templates are no longer supported. [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) or [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) are the preferred solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try them out. Although I'd still like to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a spelling mistake in your template -  change

```
alt="${userName}"
```

to

```
alt="${username}"
```

It probably fails silently without it.

It also looks like `${attributes}` got removed somehow from your deployed app.

Comment: Thanks, just tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: Well it worked for me and i just tried it too ;)

Comment: @Ankur do you use some server-side templating engine that  uses `${}`syntax? It looks like you do, cause it got removed from your markup.

Comment: what is ${attributes} ... I can't see that variable?

Comment: Ah I see, yes you're right. I feel pretty stupid atm

Comment: I think I'll take a look at mustache.js - You did solve the question, so will select as correct. Thanks again.